# Child object property change fires parents DependencyPropertyChanged callback?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, dependencyobject

In defining a base class inheriting an the `Animatable`, class, I have discovered what I am finding to be some odd behavior.

When I create a Child DependencyProperty within a 'Parent' class, then define an instance of that 'Parent' class, then alter a property on the parents child, the PropertyChangedCallback I defined for the Parents Child property fires.

In compliance with the requisite [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace MCVE {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Program {
        [STAThread]
        public static int Main( ) {
            Parent p = new Parent( );
            p.Child.Trigger = new object( );
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public abstract class Base : Animatable {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TriggerProperty;
        static Base( ) =>
            TriggerProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Trigger", typeof( object ), typeof( Base) );
        public object Trigger {
            get => this.GetValue( TriggerProperty );
            set => this.SetValue( TriggerProperty, value );
        }
    }
    public class Parent : Base {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildProperty;

        static Parent( ) {
            ChildProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Child", typeof( Child ), typeof( Parent ),
                new PropertyMetadata(  null as Child, _OnChildChanged ) );

            void _OnChildChanged(
                DependencyObject sender,
                DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e ) =>
                Console.WriteLine( "Child Changed!" );
        }

        public Parent( ) : base( ) =>
            this.Child = new Child( );


        public Child Child {
            get => this.GetValue( ChildProperty ) as Child;
            set => this.SetValue( ChildProperty, value );
        }

        protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore( ) => new Parent( );
    }
    public class Child : Base {
        public Child( ) : base( ) { }
        protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore( ) => new Child( );
    }
}
```

To reproduce:

1. Create WPF Project. Target .Net 4.7.2.
2. Select `App.xaml`
3. Under `Properties`, change `Build Action` to `Page`
4. Paste code into `App.xaml.cs`. Overwrite EVERYTHING.

Running this code, you should see the message print twice within the console.

Why is this happening? Is there a way to STOP it from happening?

Follow Up [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53919204/why-is-this-animatable-property-being-set-again):

Comment: Hi, I tried to run your code, and it threw System.TypeInitializationException exception as this line of code: "ChildProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Child", typeof( Child ), typeof( Parent ),
                new PropertyMetadata(  null as Child, _OnChildChanged ) );"

Comment: @NhanPhan Did you create the project as a console application, or as a WPF application. It needs to be a WPF application.

Comment: As a note, writing `null as Child` is redundant for two reasons. First, `null` is assignable to every reference type, second the type of the default value argument of the PropertyMetadata constructor is `object`.

Comment: @Clemens That's fair. It's just my own personal preference as I have some utility methods for registering dependency properties, one expecting a `default` value and one expecting a `PropertyMetaData`, so it tends to get upset if I don't explicitly provide the property type by `null as Foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message print 2 times in console because Child property was set 2 times:

- 1st time in Parent constructor( this.Child = new Child( );)
- 2nd time    when you call p.Child.Trigger = new object( );

I think in your case, you can compare **new value and old value of Child property** in _OnChildChanged() to prevent the problem:

```
            void _OnChildChanged(
                DependencyObject sender,
                DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.NewValue != e.OldValue)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Child Changed!");
                }
            }
```

Regards!

Comment: wonderful. so why is the property being set the second time without my having explicitly done so? Guess that will need to go into a new question...