# Why is this Animatable property being set again?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, dependencyobject

Follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53918882/child-object-property-change-fires-parents-dependencypropertychanged-callback) question.

Apparently, for some reason after having explicitly set the `Parent.Child` property ( either inside the constructor or explicitly outside of the constructor ), when I set the `Child.Trigger` property of the `Parent.Child` object, the `Parent.Child` object is being set yet again. This can be observed by breaking on the `_OnChildChanged` method defined within the static constructor. On the second instance of it being called, you can see that `e.OldValue` is not null, and that it is the same as `e.NewValue`.

WHY is the `Child` property of `Parent` being set yet again when setting the `Trigger` property?

In compliance with the requisite Minimal, [Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace MCVE {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Program {
        [STAThread]
        public static int Main( ) {
            Parent p = new Parent( );
            p.Child.Trigger = new object( );
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public abstract class Base : Animatable {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TriggerProperty;
        static Base( ) =>
            TriggerProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Trigger", typeof( object ), typeof( Base) );
        public object Trigger {
            get => this.GetValue( TriggerProperty );
            set => this.SetValue( TriggerProperty, value );
        }
    }
    public class Parent : Base {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildProperty;

        static Parent( ) {
            ChildProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Child", typeof( Child ), typeof( Parent ),
                new PropertyMetadata( null as Child, _OnChildChanged ) );

            void _OnChildChanged(
                DependencyObject sender,
                DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e ) =>
                Console.WriteLine( "Child Changed!" );
        }

        public Parent( ) : base( ) =>
            this.Child = new Child( );


        public Child Child {
            get => this.GetValue( ChildProperty ) as Child;
            set => this.SetValue( ChildProperty, value );
        }

        protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore( ) => new Parent( );
    }
    public class Child : Base {
        public Child( ) : base( ) { }
        protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore( ) => new Child( );
    }
}
```

To reproduce:

1. Create WPF Project. Target .Net 4.7.2.
2. Select `App.xaml`
3. Under `Properties`, change `Build Action` to `Page`
4. Paste code into `App.xaml.cs`. Overwrite EVERYTHING.

Comment: As a note, it's wrong to use `typeof(Parent)` in the registration of the Trigger propety, because the class that registers the property is `Base`. You also don't need a static constructor for the registration. Just write `public static readonly DependencyProperty TriggerProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Trigger), typeof(object), typeof(Base));`

Comment: @Clemens: Crud. Artifact left over from copy-pasting. Updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look on implementation of the **Animatable** class. It is inherited from **freezable** class which is inherited from **DependencyObject** class.

Inside **freezable**, it overwrote **OnPropertyChanged** event from the **DependencyObject** and invoke all handlers which is response to a changing dependency property of type Freezable.

That mean when any dependency value in Child class has changed, **OnPropertyChanged** event in Freezable class will be called. And the **FireChanged() has** called also. Inside **FireChange()** method, it will call **GetChangeHandlersAndInvalidateSubProperties** to check all changed from sub class, and then the **_OnChildChanged** will be invoked whenever any its dependency property has changed.

You can refer source code of Freezable class [here](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/wpf/src/Base/System/Windows/Freezable@cs/1305600/Freezable@cs)

---

This behavior is also documented in [Freezable Objects Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/freezable-objects-overview), section [Creating Your Own Freezable Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/freezable-objects-overview#creating-your-own-freezable-class)
 (emphasis mine):

> A class that derives from Freezable gains the following features.
>
> - Special states: a read-only (frozen) and a writable state.
> - Thread safety: a frozen Freezable can be shared across threads.
> - Detailed change notification: Unlike other DependencyObjects, Freezable objects provide **change notifications when sub-property values change**.
> - Easy cloning: the Freezable class has already implemented several methods that produce deep clones.

Comment: I believe I understand then. So any change to `Bar` in `Foo.Bar` will fire the `DependencyPropertyChanged` callback defined for `BarProperty` in `Foo`. This is good to know and explains a lot of the behavior I've been seeing in my project. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Will, " So any change to Bar in Foo.Bar will fire the DependencyPropertyChanged callback defined for BarProperty in Foo" this one is correct only if you change any dependenceproperty in Bar( normal property in Bar will not effect to Foo.Bar).